# Persistence Unit not started, when only using @Transactional

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, jta, java-ee-7

I am using Wildfly 10.1.0 and I am trying to change all the EJB's to only use `@Transactional` annotations, which are provided since Jave EE 7 (because of JTA 1.2). The thing is when my project has 0 EJB's, the PersistenceUnit is not started by the container. If I add an empty class with only the annotation `@Stateless` then it works again.

This is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.1">
  <persistence-unit name="Storage-PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/PostGreDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>SomeEntity<class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What is the reason why the PersistenceUnit is not started, when there are no EJB's available?

Comment: Is there anything left that uses it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the reason why the PersistenceUnit is not started, when there are no EJB's available?

The reason is that in a JEE application the Persistence Context (including DB connection, Persistence Units and stuff) is started and managed by the EJB container:

[image]

So, just annotating beans methods at the Web tier with `@Transactional` is not enough to get Persistence Context started. Beware that transactions are also managed by the EJB container, not the Web Container.

See [Java Platform, Enterprise Edition: The Java EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/overview007.htm) for further details on JEE architecture.